# Right function with character and integer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a SELECT statement where I need to compare the month of a date field to the 2 left characters in a VarChar field.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  So I broke the 2 pieces out and ran the following code (I simplified it by removing fields irrelevant to this issue):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  .
  .
  .
    '0' & Month(MaxOfRT_RENL_DT) as RT_RENL,
    Left(DED_PERIOD_START, 2) as RT_Start
FROM AS_tblTBMED;
--WHERE Right('0' & Month(MaxOfRT_RENL_DT), 2) <> Left(DED_PERIOD_START, 2);
```

When I run this, I get "0" in the RT_RENL field.  I'm guessing it's a CAST issue, but I've been away from SQL for so long I can't recall how to do this.

Sample data would look like this:

```
MaxOfRT_RENL_DT       DED_PERIOD_START
01-01-2023                0101
02-01-2023                0201
03-01-2023                0301
```

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input tables and expected output?

Comment: If you need to compare a month value cast your `DED_PERIOD_START` to an int and compare with `month()` which also returns an int

Comment: What is the actual defined data type of the date column? You'll might be a lot more efficient if you can do an integer comparison instead of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the operator + and `cast` the function month's returned value into `varchar`.

```
SELECT  '0' + cast( Month(MaxOfRT_RENL_DT) as varchar) as RT_RENL,
    Left(DED_PERIOD_START, 2) as RT_Start
FROM AS_tblTBMED;
```

With the where condition can be :

```
SELECT  '0' + cast( Month(MaxOfRT_RENL_DT) as varchar) as RT_RENL,
    Left(DED_PERIOD_START, 2) as RT_Start
FROM AS_tblTBMED
WHERE '0' + cast( Month(MaxOfRT_RENL_DT) as varchar) = Left(DED_PERIOD_START, 2);
```

As mentioned by @stu in the comment you can also cast `DED_PERIOD_START` to an int and compare it with `month()` :

```
SELECT  Month(MaxOfRT_RENL_DT) as RT_RENL,
    CAST(Left(DED_PERIOD_START, 2) AS int) as RT_Start
FROM AS_tblTBMED;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/13W4IsSP)